# Is any way to lock Android KitKat to a certain frequency/band?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, mobile-network, gsm

Normally we can lock our mobile to either LTE, WCDMA, or GSM thorough Network Mode option from setting. But I would like to lock specifically 900MHz and/or 1800MHz band, which they are included as GSM in the Network Mode. Then my question is: is any way to do that way? Prefer if I can do with command or script only without installing any application. But thorough application also will be fine too.

Comment: AFAIK such decisions like "Which frequencies are used?" are the job of the baseband, which is like an independent small OS running in parallel to Android. Android can only communicated via the Radio Interface Layer (RIL) with this system. Therefore if the RIL has no command to whitelist or blacklist frequencies you can not do what you want, as modifications to the RIL is an extreme complicated and dangerous topic (dangerous because you can easily break laws by misusing or disturbing frequencies of your MNO who will sue you for that).

Comment: I remember long ago, I could lock my Nokia phone (a featured phone non Android. So the intention to mentioned Android is could be with different OS we can do) to certain frequency channel. However, the channel still need translation to actual frequency. So, what I am asking here is the same thing. Is any way to lock android phone to certain frequency, or at least to certain band.

Comment: @AirCraftLover as Robert said, yes this can be possible but Android APIs don't offer such option. Even, I think, you can't read frequency, rather writing (I'm not a developer though). May be RILD can but that's just a binary blob. Communicating directly with BP may work, if you can find out what modem speaks. May be ATC or QMI or some other vendor specific thing. Or may be some Engineering Mode or Test Mode or Diagnostic Mode or dial code or bootloader mode or service mode may fulfill your requirement, which is again vendor/SoC specific. Generic Android (AOSP) doesn't do what you want.